# Duplicates using Node/Express/Socket.IO/Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io

My client is dropping its first socket.io message and seeing duplicates for other messages.  The server sends one message at a time but the client misses the first message, receives the second message once, the third message twice and the fourth three times, etc..   On the server side I have Node server using Express.  On the client I am using Angular.  Versions: Socket.IO:0.9.16, Node:v0.10.26, Express:4.4.4, Angular:1.2.18.  Server: Linux RH5.  Client: WinXP/Chrome 36.0.1985.97 beta-m.  Help appreciated in advance.

---

Server: test.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3011);
io.set('log level', 5);
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));

var seqNum = 1;
var connects = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log("Connected");
   connects =+ 1;
   socket.emit('status',{ status: "starting" });
   socket.emit('status',{ status: "running" });
});

setInterval(function() {
   if (connects > 0) {
      console.log("Sending: "+seqNum);
      io.sockets.emit('test', seqNum);
      seqNum++;
   }
   else
      console.log("No one yet");
}, 2000);
```

---

Client: public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="TestApp">
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" border=1>
      <h4>Msgs</h4>
      <span>Status: {{connStatus}}</span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index">{{$index + 1}}: {{msg}}</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

client: public/app.js

```
 var app = angular.module("TestApp",[]);

  // We define a factory the socket service is instantiated only once, and
  // thus act as a singleton for the scope of the application
  app.factory("socket", function ($rootScope) {
    console.log("Load io factory");
    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          socket.on(eventName, callback);
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      }
    };
  });

 function MainCtrl($scope, socket) {
    console.log("Setting stuff");
    $scope.messages = new Array;
    $scope.connStatus = "Off";

    socket.on('connect', function() {
       console.log("Connected");
       $scope.connStatus = "On";
       $scope.$apply();
    });

    socket.on('status', function(msg_in) {
       console.log("Status: "+ msg_in.status);
       $scope.connStatus = msg_in.status;
       $scope.$apply();
    });

    socket.on('test', function(msg_in) {
       console.log("Recvd: "+msg_in);
       $scope.messages.push(msg_in);
       $scope.$apply();
    });

    socket.on('error', function() {
       console.log("Error on socket");
       $scope.connStatus = $scope.connStatus + " - error";
    });
 }
```

---

Server console:

node test.js

```
   info  - socket.io started
No one yet
No one yet
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized y2eaJREuSjqvp4PthfG2
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/y2eaJREuSjqvp4PthfG2
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client y2eaJREuSjqvp4PthfG2
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
Connected
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"status","args":[{"status":"starting"}]}
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"status","args":[{"status":"running"}]}
Sending: 1
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[1]}
Sending: 2
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[2]}
Sending: 3
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[3]}
Sending: 4
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[4]}
Sending: 5
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[5]}
Sending: 6
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[6]}
Sending: 7
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"test","args":[7]}
```

---

Client console: (note the number before the line shows how many times it has been received.  The console collapses duplicate lines)

```
Load io factory
Setting stuff
Status: running
  Recvd: 2
2 Recvd: 3
3 Recvd: 4
4 Recvd: 5
5 Recvd: 6
6 Recvd: 7
```

---

Client window:

```
Msgs

Status: running
1: 2
2: 3
3: 3
4: 4
5: 4
6: 4
7: 5
8: 5
9: 5
10: 5
11: 6
12: 6
13: 6
14: 6
15: 6
16: 7
17: 7
18: 7
19: 7
20: 7
21: 7
```

Comment: `$scope.messages = new Array;` ? Double check your code.

Comment: $scope.messages = [];  Produces the same results.  What do you suggest?

Comment: why `track by $index` ? Remove it and try again.

Comment: My data is keyless and can have dupes.  Track by index tells angular to use the array position as the index.  I appreciate that you are trying to help.  Perhaps if you ran the code yourself and told me if you experience the same thing that could be more telling.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, upgraded to socket.io 1.0.6 and the same thing occurs.

Comment: At someone recommednation I have moved the inclusion of socket.io after the angular include but that did not change anything.

Comment: The issue is definitely with the way the service is setup.  I moved the socket.io code to the Controller for now and this works fine.  As a service I never saw multiple connections or initialization but somehow as a service I get ever increasing duplicates.    It feels like the service is being duplicated on every message.

Comment: I moved the socket definition out of the factory (aka service) and put it in the controller and it works for now.